# TinyMCE5 disable certain toolbar buttons and menu options

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I am trying to disable some toolbar and menu options of tinyMce but I could not find a proper way to do it, base on what i found I came up with something like this:

```
   const buttons = this.editor.ui.registry.getAll().menuItems;
    for (let id in buttons) {
        if (buttons.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            let button = buttons[id];
            button.disabled = !enabled;
        }
    }
```

Based on the code of tinymce below disabled is a valid property on the button but it does not do anything when i set it to true, any ideas?

```
interface BaseToolbarButtonSpec<I extends BaseToolbarButtonInstanceApi> {
    disabled?: boolean;
    tooltip?: string;
    icon?: string;
    text?: string;
    onSetup?: (api: I) => (api: I) => void;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Button API, almost every API in TinyMCE is unstable so you will have to figure out the exact methods around `disabled` or `enabled` depending on your specific version.

TinyMCE 5 is not supported so I will answer for 6: Reference: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/custom-basic-toolbar-button/#api

Something like:

```js
const buttons = this.editor.ui.registry.getAll().menuItems;
for (let id in buttons) {
    if (buttons.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        let button = buttons[id];
        button.setEnabled(!enabled);
    }
}
```

Do **not** set properties directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable and disable specific plugins with the `menubar` and `toolbar` options in the TinyMCE.init, or set them both to `"false"` to completely disable all the toolbar buttons and menu options:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [ "plugin-names" ],
    menubar: "false",
    toolbar: "false",
});
```

You can modify specific menu items and toolbar items by:

1. Taking plugin names out of the toolbar list
2. Using [the `removed_menuitems` option](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/menus-configuration-options/#removed_menuitems) to take away the menubar items you don't need. The [docs have a list of all the menubar item names](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/menus-configuration-options/#example-the-tinymce-default-menu-items) for the Tiny config.

For example, this configuration takes out several menu items:

```
removed_menuitems: "newdocument, preview, visualblocks, image, bold, inserttable,  cell, row, column, advtablesort, tableprops, deletetable, help"
```

Here's how it works in the editor UI, before and after image:

[[image: Two configurations of TinyMCE 5 compared, one with a default menu, and one with specific menu items removed1]